# scroll views and RecyclerView at same time

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, scrollview

**want to scroll RecyclerView and views in scroll view, in this code scroll only work on views but not scroll the RecyclerView or scroll hide the RecyclerView.I am using nested scrollview but same not working.**

> scroll views and RecyclerView like as one layout is scrolling.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrol"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topRl5"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/nested_scrol"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="visible">

                    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
                        android:id="@+id/chart1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_300sdp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/weekly_summary"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/grey_light"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:text="تفصیلی رپورٹ"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/daily_earning_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scrol"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <include
            layout="@layout/weekly_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is my RecyclerView i include it in main class**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_barchart"
tools:context=".guaranteeDetails.baarChart.BarChartActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/weekly_recycler_view"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_4sdp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_4sdp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

     />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use should use NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView 
And I would also recommend setting

```
Recyclerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Where is your recyclerview?